# Convert MPEG audio files downloaded through AlamoFire to mp3 files

Tags: ios, swift, audio, alamofire, mp3

I'm using the Alamofire API to download content in my iOS project. It works great but I only want to download audio content and store it to my file directory as an mp3. Mp3 files download fine, but some audio content exists that I want to download and have no path extension.  Audi content with no extension gets downloaded and can still be played from my AVAudioPlayer(), but I need to convert these files into mp3 as well.

Is there a way to convert these audio files with no extension to mp3? I tried simply adding the ".mp3" path extension, but I don't think it's that simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Download Destination 
let dest: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL:NSURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
            print("***documentURL: ",documentsURL)
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
            print("***fileURL: ",fileURL ?? "")
            return (fileURL!,[.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

// Download Operation        
Alamofire.download(url, to: dest)
            .downloadProgress(closure: {(progress) in
                print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                self.appDelegate.downloadProgressQueue[url] = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
            }).validate(contentType: ["audio/mpeg"])
            .response(completionHandler: {(complete) in
                if complete.error == nil, let filePath = complete.destinationURL?.path {
 
                   // Download Completed
 
                }
                else {
                    
                   // Download Unsuccessful

                }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

> adding the ".mp3" path extension

won't change file format.
You should convert your audio file. BUT you can't create .mp3 file on iOS Device.

Comment: As alternative, you can create .mp4 on iOS Device.